# The tensor product of smooth vector bundles is smooth

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tensor-products, vector-bundles

Let M be a smooth manifold and $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two smooth manifolds which are also vector bundles with projections
\begin{align*}
&\pi_1:E_1\to M\\
&\pi_2:E_2\to M
\end{align*}
and local trivilisations which are diffeomorphisms
\begin{align*}
&\varphi_{1}:\pi_1^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^{k_1}\\
&\varphi_{2}:\pi_2^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^{k_2}
\end{align*}
respectively.

Take the tensor product of these two vector bundles and there is the projection
\begin{equation*}
\pi: E_1\otimes E_2 \to M
\end{equation*}
and local trivilisations:
\begin{equation*}
\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times (\mathbb{R}^{k_1}\otimes \mathbb{R^{k_2}})
\end{equation*}
which can be defined by:
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(v\otimes w)=(\pi(v\otimes w), \varphi_1(v)\otimes \varphi_2(w)).
\end{equation*}

My issue is in showing that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism so that $E$ is a smooth vector bundle.

My attempt so far has been to put $U$ and $\mathbb{R}^{k_1}\otimes \mathbb{R}^{k_2}$ into local coordinates and then use $\varphi$ to have local coordinates on $\varphi^{-1}(U)$. Given this we have that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism.

But this doesn't use the fact that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are diffeomorphisms. Is this still ok?

Comment: What is the smooth structure on $E_1\otimes E_2$ to begin with?

Comment: @ArcticChar Thats what I want to know. As in given smooth structures on $E_1$ and $E_2$ does the tensor product $E_1\otimes E_2$ also have a smooth structure that we can give it? I have been trying to give it one based on the smooth structures of $E_1$ and $E_2$ but I am finding it difficult to do this.

Comment: You are supposed to use $\varphi $ to construct a local chart on $E_1\otimes E_2$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I have used $\varphi$ to construct a local chart on $E_1\otimes E_2$ by using an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^{k_1}\otimes \mathbb{R}^{k_2}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{k_1k_2}$ and using a chart for the open set $U$ of the manifold M. I looked at the transition functions and showed they were diffeomorphisms. I have looked around in books and found that no one does it like this  (they don't make charts for $E_1\otimes E_2$ to show smoothness). They say that the transition functions are $g_{1}\otimes g_{2}$ and so it is smooth. How can I see that they are smooth in an obvious way?

Comment: It is not very clear what are you confused. You said "I looked at the transition functions and showed they were diffeomorphisms", but then later "They say that the transition functions are $ g_1\otimes g_2$ and so it is smooth. How can I see that they are smooth in an obvious way?" So did you show that the transition functions are smooth?